# How do I get technical answers out of a non-technical person?

Tags: communication, helping

Our group works with a fairly complicated application that routinely has bugs crop up, meaning we have amazing job security, but also have to constantly be helping our users resolve these bugs.

One user, working in the field off their laptop, reports not being able to access the application at all.

We made a request for more information via email ticketing service.  Our requests for more data on the way they are accessing the application is met with very little response.  We ask if they are using the proper url, including the proper one in our response, and they say nothing in return.  We ask if they are using a browser, naming the ones they might be using, and they tell us they are using "Windows XP".  They completely ignore our request to tell us what sort of error they get when they try to get to our application.

I don't mean to put the blame on our user, but getting real technical information feels like pulling teeth, and the user seems always eager to provide us with minimal detail about their problem.  So maybe the fault is in me trying to ask them for information in too technical terms.

How then, besides an in-person meeting, can I get more information out of a user when looking for answers to a technical question, when the user doesn't have much technical knowledge at all?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting information from users, not about workplace dynamics.

Comment: I'd say that this falls under the "professionalism" topic I see at the help center. We certainly have a lot of questions here that deal with communication at the workplace, e.g., with supervisors or colleagues. Thus, I'd say it is on-topic.

Comment: This is about performing a specific job function not about navigating the workplace in general.  There is no workplace dynamic complicating this issue here that would bring it to be ontopic at the workplace.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from every other, "How do I get someone I work with to do something I want?" type question.

Comment: Is someone reaching out to the users and talking to them? It can be daunting for a user to explain, in an email, exactly what is going on. Moreover if they're "in the field" doing their work with a customer, it might not be possible/practical to handle traditional bug reports.

Comment: Is talking to them over the phone an option? I have found in those situations a brief phone chat can clear up much of the confusion and often get the information I need.

Comment: If getting browser details etc. is like pulling teeth, tell them to go to http://supportdetails.com/ and use the "Send Details" button at the top of the page to email you their details.

Comment: lol @ "amazing job security." Not when the product is scrapped.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds to me like you are trying to communicate by email in a situation where telephone would be more appropriate.

On a phone call, if the user doesn't understand the question, you could immediately clarify, and not worry about them not responding to the query or misunderstanding and giving a non-helpful reply.  If you can't look over the user's shoulder, and you can't remotely connect to his or her computer, at least using telephone would allow real-time back-and-forth discussion to help you extract the information you need from the user.

Answer (score 4):

> How then, besides an in-person meeting, can I get more information out
>   of a user when looking for answers to a technical question, when the
>   user doesn't have much technical knowledge at all?

Customer support for non-technical users can be a challenge if you haven't thought out the situation from their end.

Some companies provide support folks with a script, using language that is comfortable to the users. Think of the cable company - "Is your television turned on? Is your cable modem plugged in? How many lights do you see on now? ..."). You could do the same.

Some companies ask for screenshots. In some cases, that can help in the problem debugging.

Some companies provide software that aids in customer support. For example, you could install  remote-support software on their machines, guide the end user in granting permission to "take over" their computer, then you can see the problems and get the answers yourself.

If using Windows 7, the Problem Step Recorder can be very handing for this type of situation.

Some companies have their end users ship the laptop back and swap it out with another while they are fixing problems.

Comment: Using software that enables you to watch their screen or even take over control of their computer will be the best technical solution to your problem. Obviously needs checking that this is acceptable (for example if the employee sees customer data that you are not supposed to see).

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a software answer, but perhaps you should put some local logging into your app?

On startup, write to a text file & log all the particulars, especially regarding network connections.  Be sure to manage the size of the file - either wipe it out every time the program starts, or delete lines that are too old, etc.

When users have a problem, have them email the file to you.  If necessary, put a button in your app that copies the file to their desktop to make it easy to find and email.

On your support web site, include a video showing how to push the button and how to email the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to ask the users for data on their issue,it is incumbent on you to tell them in terms that they understand how to get that data to you.  Fortunately, there is software available that if installed on the user's computers, allows you to take control of their terminals (with their permission) and see for yourself what's going on. Alternatively, you can get them to send you snapshots of their screen.

Your ticketing service seems to be worthless. You'll probably need to provide them with training and as a group, you'll need to have a conversation with the manager of the ticketing service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this falls under: too technical, not enough detail, reluctance to type a lot of information or the user just making assumptions that you know how they do things: Corporate-wide browser usage rules, this person has been doing it the same way, of course I'm connected to the Internet, etc.

Don't assume users know how to give good information when there is a problem. You have to train them.

1. Provide steps to solve basic problems.
2. Give them a list of information to provide when making a request. Push the request back when they don't. Don't be arbitrary and expect everything including the kitchen sink.
3. Have your app create a log file of important information when they use the app successfully (so you know what works) and maybe another file of reported failures.

Maybe you need to get out into the field and see how they do things? It seems like there may be time issues that you assume everyone has nothing else to do but deal with this problem. Everyone manages their work differently and some things are being put in front of this problem. Just because it is at the top of your list doesn't mean it isn't at the bottom of theirs.